# How to use Stanford Parser to extract features with python

Tags: python, nlp, svm, stanford-nlp

I have included Stanford Parser in my project.Here is part of code of it.

```
def parseToStanfordDependencies(self, sentence):

        tokens, tree = self.parse(sentence)
        standoffTokens = [standoffFromToken(sentence, token)
                          for token in tokens]
        posTags = [token.tag() for token in tree.taggedYield()]
        print " ".join(["%s/%s" % (word.text, tag) for word, tag in zip(standoffTokens, posTags)])
        #print tree.taggedYield().toString(False)
        result = self.package.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure(tree)

        returnList = []
        for dependency in result.typedDependenciesCollapsedTree():

            govStandoff = standoffTokens[dependency.gov().index() - 1]
            depStandoff = standoffTokens[dependency.dep().index() - 1]

            returnList.append((str(dependency.reln()),
                               govStandoff,
                               depStandoff))

        return Dependencies(sentence, standoffTokens, posTags, returnList)
```

I am conducting a task of text classification with linear svm. I have tried

```
from stanford_parser import parser

stanford_parser = parser.Parser()
print stanford_parser.parseToStanfordDependencies("This girl I met was your sister.")
```

However,besides POS tags, I also want to use Stanford Parser to extract other syntactic features, such as Production rules. What should I do? Is anyone willing to help me? I am a newbie in Python and Natural Language Processing.